# Resetting an IPV6 interface with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, tcp, ipv6, netsh

Since netsh is going to become obsolete in the near future,I was looking for a replacement which does the equivalent to resetting the netsh ipv6 interface (`netsh interface ipv6 reset`).
I was looking for alternatives to run the above command either with powershell or any other script. On running  `netsh interface ipv6 reset`,I can see alot of operations being performed,example:
`Resetting Compartment Forwarding, OK!`
`Resetting Compartment, OK!`
`Resetting Control Protocol, OK!`
I'm not sure how exactly to go about doing all of these with powershell or any other script.Is there any way to perform the above with powershell?
From going through the references online I understand that it overwrites the following registry,
 `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\` to the default values.Where exactly is the default configuration for ipv6 stored?

Comment: Check out [similar question](https://serverfault.com/q/527278/85798) at ServerFault.

Comment: I did check this article out but for IPV6 I couldn't find any reg key.Is it Tcpip or Tcpip6?Even Tcpip6 hive was not useful in my case.

Comment: You couldn't find Tcpip6? It should be there. Full path for IPv6 `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6`.

Comment: No that i did.But in my case,the reset,according to https://serverfault.com/q/527278/85798 ,the Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\ and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dhcp are overwritten.So I tried the following:->Took a backup of the Tcpip and dhcp registries.

->Changed the ipv6 prefix policy

->Restored the Tcpip and dhcp regsitries from step 1.Still remained the same